# Managing C++ project - file layout, dependencies and version control

Tags: c++, visual-c++, makefile

I have recently started a new C++ project and I intend to make it cross-platform in time. I haven't had much experience with C++ projects before so the first thing that bothers me is that default Visual Studio file layout setup. I tried reading-up the Net on this subject but the info just seems rare and conflicting, so I started by doing something simple like this:

```
build
  vc2010  // Visual C++ solution/project files
lib 
  include // Header files for third-party libs
  // All library binaries here (like .lib, .dll or .so)
src
  // My own code (including headers)
temp
  // I use this as intermediate file output directory (for Visual C++)
```

Then Visual C++ project is configured to output final .exe in a root project directory (debug/release builds) so I can put there my own specific data as well (like `data/` dir). Please note, I intend to manage my project under source version control repository (excluding some types like .exe) and I am not writing a library here. So my questions are:

Are there any de-facto standards for structuring your projects? Or are they platform and user specific?

How do you handle library dependencies? Do you just put pre-compiled binaries (like in my setup) or use full library source code and setup your project build process to include them in the process. Is it a good idea to put binary files under version control (like .lib/.dll in this case)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep in mind what happens when you switch to a different build system on another platform.

It won't know what to do with solution/project files, they're specific to Visual Studio. So it doesn't really matter how you structure that. You'll be re-doing it anyway.

Likewise with the `temp` directory, intermediate files are specific to the build system, they don't necessarily have to be off in their own tree. You'll probably want to stick with the default for each platform, whatever that is.

With third-party dependencies, you might find they're already installed (or can be installed) on the system you're porting to, in which case you might be happy to use the installed version, or you might depend on a very specific version. Either way, pre-compiled binaries are useless on another system.

So, if you want to take your third-party dependencies with you, and compile them wherever you go, then you need to treat them like your own sources, but in another root. Version-control the source but not the binaries. If you're going to use whatever's available pre-compiled for the target platform, you'll probably find you have to do things slightly differently on different platforms but that basically you'll either stick them somewhere, or find them somewhere already installed, and put that "somewhere" in your include path (for header files) and your linker path (for binaries).

You might want to version-control the binaries to be on the safe side, or you could just make a note what version you're using, and use backup rather than version control as your insurance against them being unavailable to download in future.

If you want to design for portability from the start, it might be a good idea to set things up for two different systems at the same time. You can do this without leaving Windows - for instance try installing Code::Blocks and build with MinGW as well as what you're already doing with Visual Studio.

Also beware that a lot of the libraries you'd naturally use on Windows, simply aren't available on other platforms. The build system will be the least of your worries if you've written a GUI app based on the Windows APIs, then you want to port it to OSX.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Visual Studio (VC++ **is** usable without it), then there are some things you should be aware of. You *can* change where it gets its files from and where it puts them, so you aren't tied to its default structure. However, some of its subtools have loads of trouble with having different source files with the same name (in different directories, obviously), so that should be avoided.

Also, you have the standard Windows limitation that capitalization isn't significant in file names, so you have to stop your Unix folks from using that feature of their Unix filesystems.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this thread is over two years old, but it still appears on google search, so I will tell my own idea of this mess...

First, you must definitely decide if you want to do cross-platform development... And I don't just mean by multiple OS's but also by multiple compilers, ide's (?), and standard libraries. Even in Unix there are riffs between Linux and the BSD's, some say it's just licensing issues but the code just seems to be moving into different directions.

So, the first thing to do is to solve the problem of building your stuff, and you may just use one file that generates everything else (like CMake, bakefile or one of the others that tries to be better than make), or you can have one build directory with many build files that are maintained separately, the seconds works well when there aren't so many different platforms (and most of the time, you will have an combination of make (or one of it's variants like tup) and gcc or clang or [insert other unix based compiler here], and them you will have borland, visual studio, etc. etc.

Second, if you're writing an library you might want to separate your external headers and the rest of the code into different directories, just to ease up the task of building the library and installing the headers and compiled binaries (binaries in this case are always compiled so you might drop that compiled before binaries).

Third, there are always documentation, this is usually taken off engineering manuals, and pretty much every technical book, and sometimes forgotten by developers around, but it is important as your users won't understand your code though an crystal ball, and you might want to use something like doxygen (for C++) and docbook/markdown/... for the rest (I'm actually trying to figure out the last part, the non-technical documentation), one cool goal is to have the documentation within an repository, and as you update the documentation an build script regenerates the website, and though the use of something like git submodules, whenever someone checks out or updates their code from your code repository, their will also check out the most up to date documentation. (This is basically what maven doxia tries to do for java, even if with an horrible workflow)

So in the end you might end with an src folders, an include folder (if you have public headers), an doc folder (with your documentation), an build folder (in case of multiple build scripts), and an resources or assets folder (if you have related files, like images, translation text, xml files, file databases (like sqlite), etc.). Which if your of the lazy type like me means a whole lot of work to do, in order to setup an project (make it buildable, testable, and able to produce documentation).

About out-of-source builds, that depends on you, although some tools incentive it (CMake comes to mind), but remember to setup your repository, so that no junk files end up there, either by accident or because some clumsy developer place them there. If you must to, just place all of your build files (for ex. the ones from VC++), into an directory specific to that build file (like vcbuild), and write an install script that places binaries and the needed files, where the user want them, and you just have to configure your source control system, to ignore those directories and everything beneath them.

Answer (score 0):

Just remember, no matter how hard you try to make it portable while developing in Visual Studio, it's going to break the first time you try to build / run it on any other platform.

If you want the project to be cross-platform, then I would recommend starting with at least two platforms from the beginning (e.g., Windows & Linux) and frequently make sure it builds / runs on both.  I would also suggest starting with something other than Visual Studio...not because VS is bad...it's just not ideal for setting up a cross-platform project.  I like [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) and out-of-source builds.

If the app will have a GUI, use a portable GUI library like [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/), [QT](http://qt.nokia.com/products/), etc.

Stick with stuff that's known to be portable...[boost](http://www.boost.org/), [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/), [ODBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity), etc.